# When "Key repositories is a duplicate in ./composer.json", which one is used by composer?

Tags: php, json, composer-php, operator-precedence

I noticed I have duplicate 'repositories' keys in my composer.json for a package that I am developing.

The package is working. So, I would like to perform a 'refactoring' in the sense that I would like to fix the code without changing behavior.

If I want to fix the error, I will have to delete the duplicated key which is NOT being used.

So, the question is:

When "Key repositories is a duplicate in ./composer.json", which one is used by composer?

In other words,

- Does `composer` use the first key it finds and ignore the future keys?
- Does it ignore the former keys and use the last key that it finds?, or
- Does it merge the keys' child items in some clever way?

This is the command I am running:

```
$ composer validate
Key repositories is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 16
...
```

The composer.json looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo/bar",
  "description": "foo bar",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "type": "library",
  "repositories": [
    {"type": "composer", "url": "foo"},
    {"packagist.org": false}
  ],

  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "bar"
    }
  ],

  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer uses the [seld/jsonlint](https://packagist.org/packages/seld/jsonlint) to [detect](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Factory.php#L293) duplicate keys, but it [uses](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php#L288) `json_decode` to decode the JSON.

`json_decode` uses the last value it finds for a key:

```
>>> $json = '{"a":1,"a":10,"a":100}';
=> "{"a":1,"a":10,"a":100}"
>>> $decoded = json_decode($json)
=> {#3260
     +"a": 100,
   }
>>> $decoded->a
=> 100
```